# in react native app get location and call a state updating function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to call a function in a sequence. so first tried `setTimeout` it worked but seems slow.

then I remind Promise. I thought it is a good solution but it isn't.

this is code that I wrote and the promise part I commented out.

What I want to do is call a `_getLongLat()` and then call a `_getData()` function. because get location

takes time and in the result I got not updated component.

```
_onPress = () => {

        this._getLongLat();
        setTimeout(this._getData,500);
        //let promise = new Promise(()=>{this._getLongLat()})
        //promise.then(()=>{this._getData()});

    }
```

this is _`getLongLat()` and `_getData()`

```
_getLongLat = () => {

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {

            this.setState({...this.state, location:{ longitude: position.coords.longitude, latitude: position.coords.latitude }});

        }, (error) => {
            this.setState({message: error.message})

        }, { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 10000, maximumAge: 60*60})


        };



    _getData = () => {

            GetWeather.getWeather(this.state.location.latitude, this.state.location.longitude).then( json => {
            this.setState({...this.state, data: json });
            console.log(this.state);

        }); 

    };
```

#

this is working code of `_onPress()`

```
_onPress = () => {


        this._getLongLat()
        .then( position => {
            this.setState({
                location: {longitude: position.coords.longitude, latitude: position.coords.latitude}
            })
            return this._getData( position.coords );
        }).then(json => {
            console.log(json);
            this.setState({
                ...this.state,
                data: json                
            });
        })
        .catch(error => this.setState({ message: error.message}));



    }
```

Comment: Can you paste the code of `_getLongLat()` and `_getData()`?

Comment: While I'm not a React Native developer - I'm not certain that `navigator.geolocation` is available in React Native: the `navigator` object isn't available in NodeJS, for example, because it doesn't run a browser context - and not all browsers have a `navigator.geolocation` feature exposed - and even then you need to request the user's permission first.

Comment: Is this a Functional or Class Component?

Comment: this is class component they are in react component.

Comment: react native navigator on android is asks permission properly except ios. ios need some extra works eject project need to add some permission request to plist?

Comment: Can you give a try at this code: https://pastebin.com/Lv47sm3w ?

Comment: BTW: setState is asynchronous too, so the line:
`this.setState({ ...this.state, data: json });`
`console.log( this.state );`
won't work as you expect.
Read more on this here: https://medium.com/@wereHamster/beware-react-setstate-is-asynchronous-ce87ef1a9cf3

Comment: Also, state updates are merged by default, so `this.setState({ data: json })` will do just fine. You don't really need the `...this.state` spread operator there. More on this here: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-are-merged

Comment: thanks a lot but it seems position didn't pass through add another setState to first Promise and it worked perfectly. Incase who want to know also I call the function you gave in componentDidMount. Finally It worked as I expected.

Comment: Can you post your final working code?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use following code. I am using latest version of react native so thats why i have need to install `npm i @react-native-community/geolocation`. If  your using old version of react native no need to install npm. Please add you code inside promise and return response in `resolve` and error in `reject`. Since RN 0.60, the Geolocation module was migrated out of RN Core.Please check following link for information:-

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/geolocation

**Try this code with new version of react native>0.60.0**

```
  _getLongLat = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(info => info?resolve(info) :reject('Error'));
    });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this._getLongLat().then(value => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(value));
    });
  }
```

**Try this code with old version of react native<0.59.0**

Change `_onPress` something like this

```
  _onPress = () => {
    this._getLongLat().then(value => {
      this._getData(value);
    });
  };
```

Change `_getLongLat()` and `_getData()` something like this

```
  _getLongLat = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        position => {
          resolve(position);
        },
        error => {
          reject(error.message);
        },
        { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 10000, maximumAge: 60 * 60 }
      );
    });
  };

  _getData = value => {
    GetWeather.getWeather(value.coords.latitude, value.coords.longitude).then(
      json => {
        this.setState({ ...this.state, data: json });
        console.log(this.state);
      }
    );
  };
```